# Uploading external library license to Salesforce

Tags: integration

I want to upload a Developer license for an External JS library. Could anyone tell me where do I upload the LicenseAgreement file ? (This is necessary as the license is restricted to 1 Developer and 1 Application)

Comment: welcome to sfse Shrinivas. Would you be able to share more information on what you're trying to do or achieve ? Currently, at least to me, your question is somewhat confusing.

From where, to where do you want to upload this file, and how should it be accessible ? Factors like these can greatly determine the best solution.

Comment: Actually we have a licensed version of a JS Library. We need to include this Library in the Visual Force page. So we have included JS files in static resources. But I am unsure where exactly I should keep the License agreement file? Currently I have uploaded it to the Static resources(from my desktop). This is necessary as it verifies that this is the lone org which uses this license and any other would cause a violation. So the question here was, is it OK if its Static Resource or is there any other place which is specifically meant for this?

Answer (score 0):

If the license has to be present on the page in order for the JavaScript to run, the best place to put it is a static resource. The docs give some reasons:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm

But there are a couple of additional benefits:

1. The file will be cached by the browser - perfect for a license file
   that doesn't change very often
2. If the page is used externally and is
   not accessed over SSL, the Salesforce CDN will cache it at various
   points, reducing the latency for accessing the file.